# How to make my database connection as firebase in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using laravel framework along with firebase database , i am struggling to make default database as a firebase in **Databse.php** file for that i could not able to figure out port-number,host socket etc..,can you please explain me how to setup as a default connection in laravel ..?

```
DB_CONNECTION=firebase   //i want to make firebase
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work out alike that, because Firebase doesn't support SQL - but you can add the [`firebase-php`](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library as a composer dependency and then create a `Controller` - or even a `Provider`; you'd have to connect with a service account credentials JSON.

Comment: There's also a Laravel package for it at https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase

Comment: @jeromegamez That's even more suitable, but it still doesn't really equal `Model`... one could also synchronize data into the other direction with Cloud Functions triggers & HTTP post.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, is there any way to write eloquent queries

Comment: i want to use eloquent models for that i am using one package the data is syncing to the firebase along with my local mysql database but the relationship tables data are not reflected into my firebase database

Comment: The laravel-firebase package is just a wrapper around the SDK. As of now I don't think it's possible to convert eloquent queries to Firestore queries. There was an attempt to sync Laravel Models to the Firebase Realtime DB with https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync but that project has been abandoned.

Comment: @jeromegamez,for `kreait` package also we have to provide our local database  credentials right(mysql) ,for eloquent queries i have installed another package it's not working for related tables(post has many comments)

Comment: No local database credentials needed or used in the kreait package, it's just making calls to the Firebase REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

**This package requires Laravel 8.x and higher or Lumen 8.x and higher.**

```
composer require kreait/laravel-firebase
```

https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase

Once you have downloaded the Service Account JSON file, you can configure the package by specifying environment variables starting with FIREBASE_ in your .env file. Usually, the following are required for the package to work:

https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

```
relative or full path to the Service Account JSON file
FIREBASE_CREDENTIALS=
# You can find the database URL for your project at
```

##### https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database

FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL=https://.firebaseio.com